# I get an invalid left hand side in assignment with my code

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, syntax-error

Here is what i have fot my if statment but i get the error invalid left hand side in assigment

```
$('#equals').click(function(){
    parseInt(number, 10)= b;
    parseInt(newnumber, 10)=a;
    if(operator === "+"){
        a+b=c;
        c.toString()=c;
        totaldiv.text(c);
        testNumLength(c);   
    }
    number=""
    newnumber=""
});
```

Comment: a+b=c; is your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
parseInt(number, 10)= b;
```

So you are saying to assigning b to parseInt. You have it reversed.

```
var b = parseInt(number, 10)
```

You have the problem in multiple places.

Answer (score 3):

`a+b=c` is not possible.  The variable you are assigning to needs to be on the left side.  So, `c=a+b`.

Same goes for the next line, `c.toString()` is a function call and cannot be assigned to.

Answer (score 1):

Variable assignments require a variable name on the left and a value (or expression that computes to a value) on the right.

So change to:

```
 a = parseInt(number, 10);  
 b = parseInt(newnumber, 10);  
 ...  
 c = a+b;  
 c = c.toString();
```

Comment: Thnk you very much i was staring at this for the longest time trying to figure this out